# Rails turbolinks, two questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

I'm breaking my head around two issues I'm having with turbolinks:

1/ Sometimes it looks like turbolinks are being used, and sometimes they are not. Especially when I use url_for, it seems the request is not using turbolinks. When is it and when isn't it being used? I was under the impression that it's using turbolinks for each and every internal link.

2/ I'm trying to define a simple jQuery to generate a confirm when clicking a delete link. But I'm having difficulties to get it to work. With one solution I'm getting double confirmation screens, with the other I sometimes do get the confirm and sometimes don't (when turbolinks are used)

Is there some guide on how to set this up correctly? I do seem to experience a speed benefit with turbolinks, or is that only my imagination? Anyway, I'm kind of trying to make it work instead of just deleting the gem.

Comment: you should check the docs, everything is explained there https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks

Answer (score 0):

> - What Turbolinks concept is:

Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head. Think CGI vs persistent process.

> - Turbolinks with Rails

I will recommend to watch [Rails 4.1 Performance Fundamentals Snippet: Turbolinks](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CN0OWaLzZek).

> 2/ I'm trying to define a simple jQuery to generate a confirm when
>   clicking a delete link. But I'm having difficulties to get it to work

In order to fix this follow the below step.

**1:** You have to require `jquery-turbolinks gem` in your `Gemfile`.

**2:** Edit you `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
```

N.B: You just add `jquery.turbolinks` right after `jquery` in the js file.

For more Info check [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39123949/request-ajax-is-not-changing-a-page/39124074#39124074)

Hope this help you!.