# request ajax is not changing a page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I do have a problem. Turbolinks are off
here I create a post

```
$ ->
  createBooks = (res)->
    result = JST["templates/create_book"]
             title: res.book.title
             author: res.book.author
             description: res.book.description
             id: res.book.id
    result

 $('.new_book').bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->    
    res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)    
    result = createBooks(res)                           
    $('.drafts').append(result)
```

everything works ok. I get a link like this on my page

```
 <a class="unpublish"  data-method="post" rel="nofollow" data-remote="true" data-id="#{@id}" href="/books/14/unpublish" >Draft</a>
```

here is my skim template

```
<hr>
<p>#{@title}</p>
<p>#{@author}</p>
<p>#{@description}</p>
<div class="publishing" id="book_#{@id}""
  <a class="publish" href="/books/#{@id}/publish" data-method="post"  rel="nofollow"  data-remote="true" data-id="#{@id}">Publish</a>
</div>
```

But then when I try to click on this link nothing visible happens on the page, but xhr is sent with a propper status, no errors. Its a mystery for me.
Her is my listener

```
  $('.publish').bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) -> 
    e.preventDefault()    
    res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
    result = publishBooks(res)
    alert(result)
    book_id = "#book_" + $(this).data('id')
    $(book_id).html(result)
```

I dersperatly need some help. Any help. When I reload the page everything again works ok

Thaks to monsieur VKatz
I finally have a working ecsample!!!
look like this

```
ready = ->
   createBooks = (res)->
      result = JST["templates/create_book"]
         title: res.book.title
         author: res.book.author
         description: res.book.description
         id: res.book.id
    result

  publishBooks = (res)-> 
    result = JST["templates/publish"]  
      time: res.book.published_at
      id: res.book.id
    result

  unpublishBooks = (res)-> 
    result = JST["templates/unpublish"]      
      id: res.book.id
    result

  $('.new_book').bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->    
    res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)    
    result = createBooks(res)                           
    $('.drafts').append(result)

  $('.publish').bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->     
    res = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText)
    result = publishBooks(res)    
    book_id = "#book_" + $(this).data('id')
    $(book_id).html(result)

  $('.unpublish').bind 'ajax:success', (e, data, status, xhr) ->
     e.preventDefault()
     alert('okko okko') 

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
$(document).on('page:update', ready)
$(document).on('click', '.unpublish', ready);
```

now its working but only for class unpublished? should I set this stuff for every class like "published" etc ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add `gem 'turbolinks'` and add `//= require turbolinks` in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

**First way:** Not only we need to listen for `DOM ready` but we need also to listen for `'page"load'` as well. As my answer is respect to Jquery as I don't know `Coffee-Script` but you could change accordingly.

```
function initialize(){
    $('#your_id').click( function(){
    });
}
$(document).ready(initialize);
$(document).on('page:load', initialize);
```

---

**Second way:**

**1:** You have to require `jquery-turbolinks gem` in your `Gemfile`.

**2:** Edit you `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` file

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require turbolinks
```

N.B: You just add `jquery.turbolinks` right after `jquery` in the js file.

---

**Third Way:** bind event on `Document` object.

```
function checkAlert(){
        // ...
    }
$(document).on('click', '#owner_active', checkAlert);
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: see `turbolinks` is concept  that makes navigating your web application faster [Turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks). and about other thing Give me some time. will revert to you.